# Exception thrown in build by image_picker

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am wrestling problems with image_picker for two days now. It started yesterday noon when I tried to debug my application. It would debug fine before and as far as I remember I didn't change anything in that time. It throwed `unexpected element <queries> found in <manifest>.` error and just like the error log from today below it started Jetfier to solve the incompatibility. The error Jetfier throwed yesterday was something like `SDK location not found. Define location in local.properties or with an ANDROID_SDK_ROOT environment variable`. But SDK location was defined in local.properties and I also created the `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT` env. variable with the SDK location but the error stayed the same.

Today I cleared the flutter folder completely and I reinstalled it. After that I had some problems with device-info but eventually it was resolved. Now I am stuck here and I am making no progress whatsoever. If I remove `<queries>` in `AndroidManifest.xml`, it is put there again when try to run the program so that's not a solution.

I call it in `pubspec.yaml` as `file_picker: ^2.0.10` under dependencies and I tried `pub get`, `pub cache repair`, `pub clean` in different orders. If I remove the `file_picker` and all it's uses in the project, rest of the application runs just fine. I tried `file_picker` in another project, something a lot more basic and it also threw the same exception there.

Below is the error code. If you need anymore details let me know.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > Android resource linking failed
     C:\Users\ASUS\AndroidStudioProjects\flutterdb\intern1\build\file_picker\intermediates\library_manifest\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:9:5-15:15: AAPT: error: unexpected element <queries> found in <manifest>.


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BU�LD FAILED in 21s
The built failed likely due to AndroidX incompatibilities in a plugin. The tool is about to try using Jetfier to solve the incompatibility.
Building plugin file_picker...
Running Gradle task 'assembleAarRelease'...

C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\file_picker-2.0.10\android\src\main\java\com\mr\flutter\plugin\filepicker\FilePickerPlugin.java:10: error: cannot find symbol
import androidx.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleObserver;
                         ^
  symbol:   class DefaultLifecycleObserver
  location: package androidx.lifecycle
C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\file_picker-2.0.10\android\src\main\java\com\mr\flutter\plugin\filepicker\FilePickerPlugin.java:20: error: cannot find symbol
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.plugins.lifecycle.FlutterLifecycleAdapter;
                                                    ^
  symbol:   class FlutterLifecycleAdapter
  location: package io.flutter.embedding.engine.plugins.lifecycle
C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\file_picker-2.0.10\android\src\main\java\com\mr\flutter\plugin\filepicker\FilePickerPlugin.java:38: error: cannot find symbol
            implements Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks, DefaultLifecycleObserver {
                                                               ^
  symbol:   class DefaultLifecycleObserver
  location: class FilePickerPlugin
C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\file_picker-2.0.10\android\src\main\java\com\mr\flutter\plugin\filepicker\FilePickerPlugin.java:45: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
        @Override
        ^
C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\file_picker-2.0.10\android\src\main\java\com\mr\flutter\plugin\filepicker\FilePickerPlugin.java:49: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
        @Override
        ^
C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\file_picker-2.0.10\android\src\main\java\com\mr\flutter\plugin\filepicker\FilePickerPlugin.java:53: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
        @Override
        ^
C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\file_picker-2.0.10\android\src\main\java\com\mr\flutter\plugin\filepicker\FilePickerPlugin.java:57: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
        @Override
        ^
C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\file_picker-2.0.10\android\src\main\java\com\mr\flutter\plugin\filepicker\FilePickerPlugin.java:61: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
        @Override
        ^
C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\file_picker-2.0.10\android\src\main\java\com\mr\flutter\plugin\filepicker\FilePickerPlugin.java:66: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
        @Override
        ^
C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\file_picker-2.0.10\android\src\main\java\com\mr\flutter\plugin\filepicker\FilePickerPlugin.java:277: error: cannot find symbol
            this.lifecycle = FlutterLifecycleAdapter.getActivityLifecycle(activityBinding);
                             ^
  symbol:   variable FlutterLifecycleAdapter
  location: class FilePickerPlugin
C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\file_picker-2.0.10\android\src\main\java\com\mr\flutter\plugin\filepicker\FilePickerPlugin.java:278: error: incompatible types: FilePickerPlugin.LifeCycleObserver cannot be converted to LifecycleObserver
            this.lifecycle.addObserver(this.observer);
                                           ^
C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\file_picker-2.0.10\android\src\main\java\com\mr\flutter\plugin\filepicker\FilePickerPlugin.java:286: error: incompatible types: FilePickerPlugin.LifeCycleObserver cannot be converted to LifecycleObserver
        this.lifecycle.removeObserver(this.observer);
                                          ^
Note: Some messages have been simplified; recompile with -Xdiags:verbose to get full output
12 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUİLD FAILED in 3s

Exception: The plugin file_picker could not be built due to the issue above.
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is because  tag was introduced with new package visibility options for Android 11 and upwards (SDK 30+). Because of that, you need to update your build.gradle with a version that includes this changes. Below is a list of supported gradle options.

**'3.3.3',  '3.4.3',  '3.5.4',  '3.6.4',  '4.0.1'**

Don't forget to update your ditributionUrl in your gradle-wrapper.properties as well. For example, for gradle **4.0.1**, you should have:

distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.1.1-all.zip

**reference:** https://github.com/miguelpruivo/flutter_file_picker/wiki/Troubleshooting#android

Comment: I read that before but my dumb brain read Android 11 as SDK 11 lol. It worked, thanks.

Comment: I think you need to be "one good student" to understand :D. Funs aside, we are all learning from our mistakes.

Answer (score 22):

For those who didn't know (including myself)
there are two `build.gradle` files

1. `android/build.gradle`
2. `android/app/build.gradle`

#### step 1 inside `android/build.gradle`

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        // classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0' before
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1' // after
    }
}
```

#### step 2 inside `android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties`

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists

# BEFORE
# distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.6.2-all.zip
# AFTER
distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.1.1-all.zip
```

#### step 3 rebuild project

it might take while because it will download new gradle

Answer (score 7):

** Latest Update **

**step 1 inside android/build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    // change to build:gradle:3.6.3
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.3'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
}
```

}

**step 2 inside android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties**

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
// change distributionUrl to gradle-6.5-all.zip
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.5-all.zip
```