# File picker : unexpected element <queries> found in <manifest>

Tags: flutter, filepicker

Whenever I add [file picker package](https://pub.dev/packages/file_picker) to pubspec.yaml file and re run the app I get the following error:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
> Android resource linking failed
> D:\MY_PROJECTS\flutter_projects\health_app\build\file_picker\intermediates\library_manifest\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:9:5-15:15: AAPT: error: unexpected element  found in .

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 19s
The built failed likely due to AndroidX incompatibilities in a plugin. The tool is about to try using Jetfier to solve the incompatibility.
Building plugin cloud_firestore...
Running Gradle task 'assembleAarRelease'...
Exception: The plugin cloud_firestore could not be built due to the issue above.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64502943/exception-thrown-in-build-by-image-picker

Answer (score 14, accepted):

found the solution [here](https://github.com/miguelpruivo/flutter_file_picker/wiki/Troubleshooting#-issue)

Build is failing with unexpected element  found in .

Possible solution:
This is because  tag was introduced with new package visibility options for Android 11 and upwards (SDK 30+). Because of that, you need to update your build.gradle with a version that includes this changes. Below is a list of supported gradle options.

3.3.3

3.4.3

3.5.4

3.6.4

4.0.1
Don't forget to update your ditributionUrl in your gradle-wrapper.properties as well. For example, for gradle 4.0.1, you should have:

`distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.1.1-all.zip`