# I the error "unexpected element <queries> found in <manifest>", how to fix it?

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, android-layout, android-manifest

[this is the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t4Ff2.png)

> play-services-ads-lite-19.6.0/AndroidManifest.xml:27:5-38:15: AAPT: error: unexpected element `<queries>` found in `<manifest>`.

This is the error.

Comment: On Stack Overflow, please don't show pictures of text and code.  Copy the text into the question itself and format it so that it's easy to read, copy, and search.  You can edit the question to correct this using the edit link at the bottom.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

I also had same issue on Android Studio 4.1.1, suddenly, 2 days ago.
I solved the issue by upgrading build gradle version.

- previous setting in `build.gradle` file of project was:

  ```
  classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3")
  ```
- current setting:

  ```
  classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.4")
  ```

The issue was gone immediately. :)

Comment: yeah its done thank you

Comment: for me, I also had to update my firebase-analytics to 17.5.0

Comment: Your suggestion solved to my issue. This exception thrown when i use @react-native-firebase/admob package. Thanks, you are saved my time :)

Comment: people really are fast to judge saying that the question needs details but somehow this answer the "not clear question". anyways, this also resolves my issue. thanks

Comment: heres a better answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/64524816