# Why I cannot add admob banner?

Tags: admob

I am trying to add *admob banner* but I failed. There is a some problem in mainfest.

```
C:\Users\Nady\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\c304f603f74183b8376179f99c52c5ba\play-services-ads-lite-19.6.0\AndroidManifest.xml:27:5-38:15: AAPT: error: unexpected element <queries>
```

Comment: Please add a code example that doesn't work for you. Add it by editing your post with a question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65182767/i-the-error-unexpected-element-queries-found-in-manifest-how-to-fix-it Update build.gradle