# My project crash after implementing admob

Tags: android, admob

I am running android 3.5. my project was running smoothly, but crash after i implement admob in  the code and it is giving me the error bellow:
`C:\Users\HP\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\c304f603f74183b8376179f99c52c5ba\play-services-ads-lite-19.6.0\AndroidManifest.xml:27:5-38:15: AAPT: error: unexpected element <queries> found in <manifest>.`

Please how do I solve?

Comment: error: unexpected element found in . Then what add full error

Comment: Some words have been omitted, unexpected element'query' found in 'manifest'

Comment: Can you add your manifest?

Answer (score 0):

As in this answer: [I the error "unexpected element <queries> found in <manifest>", how to fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65182767/i-the-error-unexpected-element-queries-found-in-manifest-how-to-fix-it)

While you are using the latest Admob SDK you are using old versions of build.gradle and Android Studio! You have to update!

Answer (score 0):

Use newer version of gradle,like so:

**project/android**

```
classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0")
```

**current setting:**

```
classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.4")
```

Comment: You should add a comment to your answer. Like "use a newer version of cradle"